# How in the world did I fail this audit?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

So a few minutes ago I got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883265/infinite-wacky-race) question as an audit review ([link to audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/2093390)).

When I saw it in the review queue, it looked to me (it showed as having 0 answers/votes) that quite obviously it lacked proper context. And so, I failed the audit by flagging it as "needs more context". (because it didn't include proper background/motivation)

My question is, how did I fail the audit by flagging it as needing more context? Is it just because it was received well by the community, or by what reason does it not lack proper context?

Comment: I think you're asking about the mechanics of this audit. Yes, the system chose some random question that was well-received by the community and failed you for not coming to the same conclusion. Whether it's worthwhile to try to always agree with an automated system is a different question.